# How do I integrate git with emacs?

Tags: 11.04, emacs, git

What do I need to install to be able to do something like the lines below in Ubuntu 11.04?

```
M-x git-status
git-commit-file command (c key)
git pull
git push
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

emacs has inbuilt support for git. If you are using old version of emacs (say 22.1) you might want to install 'magit' plugin. I like using magit in any version since it is way better than the generic inbuilt.

here are few key bindings generate (got by pressing C-x v C-h in a git repo dir)

```
Global Bindings Starting With C-x v:  
key             binding  
---             -------  

C-x v +     vc-update  
C-x v =     vc-diff  
C-x v D     vc-root-diff  
C-x v I     vc-log-incoming  
C-x v L     vc-print-root-log  
C-x v O     vc-log-outgoing  
C-x v a     vc-update-change-log  
C-x v b     vc-switch-backend  
C-x v c     vc-rollback  
C-x v d     vc-dir  
C-x v g     vc-annotate  
C-x v h     vc-insert-headers  
C-x v i     vc-register  
C-x v l     vc-print-log  
C-x v m     vc-merge  
C-x v r     vc-retrieve-tag  
C-x v s     vc-create-tag  
C-x v u     vc-revert  
C-x v v     vc-next-action  
C-x v ~     vc-revision-other-window
```

Comment: So if I do "C-x v v" to register and "C-x v v" again to commit, how to I do a "git push" to master remote afterwards?

Comment: @avilella, if you want to push & pull please install [magit](https://github.com/magit/magit). Magit has push, pull commands and interactive status buffer which is very handy to look at your changes. [here](https://github.com/yyr/emacsd/blob/master/config/init-git.el) you can find my settings for magit

Answer (score 3):

In 12.04 and 14.04 git-status requires:

```
# apt-get install git-el
```

I would be surprised if that was not also true for 11.04 when this question was first asked 3 years ago.